# How to do a multipe group by in Query builder Form Type

Tags: php, symfony, query-builder, symfony-3.4

I want to do a multiple grouping.
for exemple:

- company

  - category

    - under-Category 1
    - under-category 2

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $categorieRepo = $options['repo'];
    $entreprise = $options['entreprise'];
    $builder ->add('myCategories', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => Categorie::class,
            'query_builder' => $categorieRepo->findCategorieQueryBuilder($entreprise, false),
            'group_by' => function (Categorie $categorie) {
                 return is_null($categorie->getEntreprise()) ? null : $categorie->getEntreprise()->getNom();
             },
            'required' => true,
            'choice_label' => function (Categorie $categorie) {
                return $categorie->getNom();
            },
        ))
}
```

I did a simple grouping

- company

  - categories

Comment: Please provide clearer code and a larger portion of it, to understand what you want to do. $qb is a Doctrine QueryBuilder?

Comment: can you dump the errors please?

Comment: i don't have any error juste i can't do a multiple regrouping using query_builder